# Why am I getting September 23 when the condition is to get out of the loop once it finds August

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation, webautomation, selenium-java

I'm trying to automate where I'll be choosing August 23 in the date. But what is happening is that instead of August it taking another click and it lands on September. Why is that? It seems that my code is correct but I can't figure it out. Also the sysout inside the while loop can't catch up and I have no idea why as well.

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("form-field-travel_comp_date")).click();

        while (!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='cur-month']")).getText().contains("April")) {
            System.out.println("Current month: " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='cur-month']")).getText());
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month'] //*[local-name()='svg']"))).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month'] //*[local-name()='svg']")).click();
        }

        List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'flatpickr-day')]"));
        int count = dates.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String text = dates.get(i).getText();
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("19")) {
                dates.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

I tried applying explicit wait and even Thread.sleep but to no avail. Can somebody help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: not sure, but you are clicking twice there... one with a webdriverwait, and then right afterwards without one.  Don't quite understand the loop there though... it's running while the current month does not contain "April"?  So... I'd expect you to end up with May or June.  Maybe click until current month does contain the month you want?